# Hosting private server Opencpu

Tags: opencpu

I wonder if it is possible to only connect to my own Opencpu server , hosted on AWS , inside javascript. Or do I still need to call Opencpu open cloud server inside javascript anyway? Total beginner with Opencpu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to connect to any OpenCPU cloud server if you have your own one. I have a server installed on my own computer and I even can run my OpenCPU apps offline, so I'm pretty sure about that.